# PoEdit doesn't recognize _n() plurals

Tags: php, localization, gettext, poedit, xgettext

I've got this set in source keywords of POEdit:

```
_
__
_e
_ex
_n
esc_attr_e
_x
_nc
```

It works but I gets only first string when I use `_n()` function (Twenty Eleven theme):

`<?php printf(_n('One Comment', '%s Comments', get_comments_number(), 'twentyeleven'), number_format_i18n(get_comments_number())); ?>`

Any ideas how to make it recognize `_n()`? That's exactly what I'm having problem with but there is no solution: http://www.poedit.net/trac/ticket/307

Answer (score 12):

You should set up a keyword in poedit so that you have

**Keywords**

```
n
_n:1,2
```

For example, here is my source keywords

[image: plural form poedit]

Answer (score -1):

Keyword specification is exhaustively explained in the [xgettext man page](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html).